# add a className for every 12th item in array skipping first 14 items and last 14 items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, conditional-statements, jsx

I want to add a "pagebreak" className to my div when every 12 element passes in the array like 12, 24, 48... and the first and last 14 elements should be skipped.

```
{orderData.map((el, i) => {
  let condition = i >= 14 && i % 12 === 0; // how to write the condition here ?
  return (
    <tr className={`item ${condition && "pagebreak"}  `}>
      // ... 
    </tr>
  )
})}
```

Comment: @HassanImam ... nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition for setting a *page-break* class-name is as follows ...

```
const isPageBreak =
  ((idx + 1) % 12 === 0) && // - every 12th item ... except for ...
  (idx >= 13) &&            // - skip first 14 items.
  (idx < arr.length - 14);  // - skip last 14 items.
```

Test code ...

```js
console.log([

    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
    11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
    21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
    31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,
    41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,
    51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,
  //62,
  
  ].map((item, idx, arr) => {
    const isPageBreak =
      ((idx + 1) % 12 === 0) && // - every 12th item ... except for ...
      (idx >= 13) &&            // - skip first 14 items.
      (idx < arr.length - 14);  // - skip last 14 items.

    return item + (isPageBreak ? ' :: pagebreak' : '');
  })
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 {orderData.map((el, i) => {
            
           if(i >14 && i% 12 ===0 && i < orderData.length - 14 ){
            return (
              <tr className={`... `}>
              )
         }
      return (
              <tr >
              )
})
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.